# Max of the reversed of two numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

Given two real numbers (postive or negative) in the limits of float pointing number data types, i.e., (\$-3.4e38\$ to \$3.4e38\$) not inclusive, you should output the max of the two reversed numbers.

---

### TEST CASES

### Example

### Input:

```
135
210
```

### Output:

```
531
```

\$531\$ is \$135\$ reversed, which is greater than \$012\$, i.e., \$210\$ reversed.

---

Negative numbers are allowed:

### Example 2

### Input:

```
-135
-210
```

### Output:

```
-012
```

\$-012\$ is \$-210\$ reversed, which is greater than \$-531\$, i.e., \$-135\$ reversed.

---

Real numbers are allowed:

### Example 3

### Input:

```
13.5
10
```

### Output:

```
5.31
```

\$5.31\$ is \$13.5\$ reversed, which is greater than \$01\$, i.e., \$10\$ reversed.

---

### Example 4

### Input:

```
-1112313.5
-312.5671
```

### Output:

```
-5.3132111
```

\$-5.3132111\$ is \$-1112313.5\$ reversed (it reverses the number but is still negative, which is greater than \$-1765.213\$, i.e., \$-312.5671\$ reversed.

---

### Example 5

### Input:

```
0.0000001
0
```

### Output:

```
1000000.0
```

\$1000000.0\$ is \$0.0000001\$ reversed, which is greater than \$0\$, i.e., still \$0\$ reversed.

---

### Example 6

### Input:

```
121
121
```

### Output:

```
121
```

Both numbers are equal and are palindrome. Either one is correct.

---

## Rules

- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/20634) apply
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

---

### Good Luck!

Comment: I think this would be a decent challenge if you remove the bonuses, which are [widely regarded as a bad idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/20260) in addition to your particular ones being [unobservable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197/20260) and [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260). I can see why you wanted to restrict built-ins to avoid more boring solutions, but we've seen time and time again that there's not a good way to define these for a wide class of languages, and solvers wind up mostly just probing the edges.

Comment: Also, the examples you explain are good, but you should add lots of test cases probing the more subtle points, for example like negatives combined with decimal points, and other instances of leading zeroes. One question is, what happens if the input is a number like `12.99999999999999999999999` that is beyond the float precision of a language, and so it's rendered as `-13`? I'd suggest putting some limit on decimal precision of inputs to avoid this, unless you think it's particularly important.

Comment: @xnor thanks for the feedback, will edit it to make it a better challenge.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: So, `10.0` would reverse to `0.01`, while `10` would reverse to `01` or `1`? Some languages might consider `10` and `10.0` equal or even not distinguish them at all. It seems like it's really a number string that's the input. I guess it don't matter since probably everyone will take the number as a string anyway (which is allowed by default).

Comment: Exactly! If you want to treat as a string, it's fine too!

Comment: There are two example 4s and the first one is wrong (answer should be `-5.3132111`

Comment: @NickKennedy nice catch, thank you! updated it

Comment: Now there are two example 5s :P

Comment: The rule for real numbers is strange. Just consider \$ 1 = 0.{\dot {9}} \$...

Comment: Thanks @Night2 no two 6s  now tho!

Comment: Your test cases show some extraneous `0`s in the results, like `-012` or `1000000.0`. Are these `0`s required in the output, or could you output `-12` and `1000000`?

Comment: Yeah sry for the confusion, you can output both ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

+1 byte to fix cases when only one of the inputs is negative.
-1 byte by Grimmy

```
í'-δ†Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Fp13XNbHjUsiPr/P1pJ19DQ0MjY0FjPVElHydjQSM/UzNxQKRYA)

[Test all inputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W6fL/8Fp13XNbHjUsiPpfaa@k8KhtkoKSvc7/6GglQ2NTJR0lI0MDpVidaCVdCFcXxjc01gPx4bKGhkbGUDFdY0MjPVMzc0OwlIGeARgYAmWgWo1AbBCJoRWhMxYA)

The input is taken as a list of strings [x, y].

Explanation:

```
í        Reverse each input
 '-      Push a minus sign
   δ†    Apply "filter out the minus sign to the front" to each input
     Z   Take the maximum
```

Comment: Unfortunately it fails on test 5 : [0.0000001,0] just take input as string may fix it.. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaoCh13UcNC/7/j1Yy0DMAA0MlHSUDpVgA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: Yes, you are right. I must have overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: I think it also fails if only the second string is negative, as in this example: https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOaoCh13UcNC/7/j1bSNTQ0NDI2NNYzVdJRMjY00jM1MzdUigUA

Comment: Thanks. To fix this, it seems like I have to filter out the minus sign to the front before I take the maximum, so the byte count went up by 1, since I had to replace `€` with `ε }`

Answer (score 6):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), <del>126</del> 124 bytes

As always Wren is the longest. I hate Wren's verbosity.

```
Fn.new{|a|a.map{|i|i>0?"":"-"+(i.abs.toString[-1..-(i.abs.toString.count)])}.map{|i|Num.fromString(i)}.reduce{|x,y|x<y?x:y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDsIgFEV/xTBBLC@txqWxdnN06Wg6IFJDUsBQsCWl3441xsX1nOTcO1qh04vZTec1r9JZgxbjHFlkoNhzjjLKU14jVCKKtlgCuw3gTOOs1I8rLQDoHwRuvHakJcsvcPEKOmvU12O5Givunos5TlmI0zHUUxmWJTVhcELBaKUT@PMHOOt7vM7sDxndFXlLSHoD)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{                                                                                                              // new anonymous function
       |a|                                                                                                           // with the parameter a
          a.map{|i|                                                                                                  // for each item in this parameter
                                  (i>0)?"":"-"                                                                       // The sign of each item. If the item is larger than 0, return the null string, otherwise return a negative sign.
                                              +(                                           )                         // Append this with the following string:
                                                i.abs                                                                // The absolute value of i
                                                     .toString                                                       // Convert this value to a string
                                                              [-1..-(i.abs.toString.count)]                          // Reverse this string
                   Num.fromString(                                                          )                        // convert this to a number from a string
                                                                                             }.reduce{|x,y|x<y?x:y}} // Find the minimum value of the list
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes:

```perl
sub f{($x,$y)=map{/-?/;$&.reverse$'}@_;$x>$y?$x:$y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1Ba4NAEIXv@yuGMLQK7mZnF1PQahrotbfclxQmVDBUXNMq4m@36zYPBua9j3nTcd/m6@rvn3CdExwznNLqdunmvTzuS3xSPf9w7xmflzdX4ljjdMSxwGlZ757hzH4oio/vnmEIq6/qQyl@v5qWk9f30/lUp7OAoNv0350hp5Xv2mYoY974BK6PtxkgZ7DDEXCCqg5ul5ZiEc5tTc4JsjkY0pBbEnIzcnNSkwlI5bAhFRmRsTGSlozKDy8EckPWBCS00lEEOtxEKS3IEDxm/QM)

...or if using a function from a core module is allowed (`max` in `List::Util`) it's 35 bytes:

## 35 bytes:

```perl
sub f{max map{/-?/;$&.reverse$'}@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxRa4MwFIXf8ysuJUwFk@YmpIM63Qp73N7a59BBygLKxNhNEX@7S7IduHDO@Ti3t0Ort7u38Ob8eDxeRtdC1l2nrNr8/QNuS/DQXftlz573FX3gg/22g7c0W1/MmpZnG5fvX4OFMVhfN4eK/Hy61uZPr6fzqSkWAkHdnNOppHNJbVH7vnVjlXrnc7j9oaIEakvY0QnoDHUT0q6oyEqMiZ@MIag0SBSgFRIWA4uJCZQBcQ0R8cQQpUoVUyi5PjwisIiUDIgILpIQRNgkcUFQIvzf9gs)

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 63 bytes

```sh
for x;a+=(${(M)x#-}${(j::)${(Oas::)x#-}})
<<<$a[1+$[a[1]<a[2]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsMgEEX3nkKoC4egOCM2kNojlB5AXLiR0k2h2YSEnN2OSQfmz/uPWedXqxp0q5@vXG5luGu16QcsF7MzvKcJ@DzLzNDdDiLGqErCQSXOHEuinHMDIapEHyShYzIdzcnobZB/i0j@6MYj2XAdkbWz7hyUxz9h3/YD)

`${x#-}` removes the leading `-` if it exists. Adding the `(M)` flag causes the `-` to be substituted instead of what remains.
Then this construct reverses the remaining string: `${(j::)${(Oas::)var}}`.

For each element, we append to an array, then use a comparison to index into the array.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>89</s> 86 bytes

<s>Disclaimer: This answer does not work for the second example #4 due to floating point accuracy constraints in Python. Feel free to disqualify.</s>

Update: This answer now works for all examples thanks to @JonathanAllan

```python
f=float
r=lambda a:-f(a[:1:-1])if eval(a)<0else f(a[::-1])
m=lambda a,b:max(r(a),r(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCsMgEEX3OYU7FaI4SlqQ5iSliwmNNKBJsKG0p7dR2kDT2Qz892b482u5TaNJybXOT7hUsfUYuisStMIxPFuwAi58cKR/oGfIT6r3954UVlAVtpO6swGfLK5aHVnHeZrjMC4sMAqmoTWhGhTlvNpi8cnFHoCRBfz5ANp8oTCgZXM4wo@jpMoD2dg91SXMa@32Bg)

Comment: It isn't floating point inaccuracy that breaks example 5, it's that `str(0.0000001)` is `'1e-07'` which, when reversed, is an invalid input to `float`. Take strings and use `eval` - you'll need to switch to`<0` but  it's [shorter](https://tio.run/##ZY5BCsMgEEX3OYU7FaI4SlqQ5iSliwmNNKBJsKG0p7dR2kDT2Qz892b482u5TaNJybXOT7hUsfUYuisStMIxPFuwAi58cKR/oGfIT6r3954UVlAVtpO6swGfLK5aHVnHeZrjMC4sMAqmoTWhGhTlvNpi8cnFHoCRBfz5ANp8oTCgZXM4wo@jpMoD2dg91SXMa@32Bg) anyway :)

Comment: Also `m=` is unnecessary, it may be [unnammed](https://tio.run/##ZYzRCoIwFIbvfYrdbQMnOxsWjHyS6uJIjoRNZUrU0y83MsjOzYHv@/in13IfBx19c4kOfXtDgmVrPD5ZYMjLwFrOC9tYN@JShGZrjLAMzwaMgCvvLeke6Nb@JDs3dyS7rOIU@mFhnlHQNS0JVSDpuvjF4sPFXoCusvjrAZTepNCgqvpwhJ9GVjIdpGI3qjJMj/P4Bg). For even more savings see my [Python 3.8 entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195248/53748).

Comment: '%.16f'%a fixes the 0.0000001

Comment: @JonathanAllan That solution with eval is clever. Answer updated with credit

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin The reason I didn't go with this as a solution is that all you need to do to find a new input number that will break things is add some more zeros

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 100 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>Math.max((g=n=>(s=n>0||-1)*[...(s*n).toFixed(9).replace(/\.0+$/,0)].reverse().join``)(a),g(b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY6xcsIwDIZ3noKhg0SxYtmXch2csVufoOUOE0waLthcnOMYeIDOfcS@SDAwJaBBg/R9v7SzRxvLtj50woeN67emt6ZYm@LTdj@0tyeAynhTQDS@kOezYJx9ERHEmUfqwkd9cht4R2rdobGlg@yb5OtLNpe4TLOja6MDpF2o/WqFYHFewRqxL4OPoXHUhAq2wDpHUCwRp4PKsmmueTKExY0WD3iChWQ1GUdTop9H05NsZqXvjtCsKH9bcFIT/f/7dxW0SsjIkiRvxQiDO8ni@4bk@C2V4Gt7fCtN@ws)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda*v:max(map(lambda x:(-1)**(z:=eval(x)<0)*float(x[z:][::-1]),v))
```

An unnamed function accepting 2 (actually, any number of) strings, which yields the maximal reversed version as a floating point number.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzJCsIwGITvPkVuWUhK/oSqBOuLxBxStCh0CaWU2JePXazOZZhvhgnv4dm1@hz6VBW3VPumvHs2msZH0vhANoCiIQIoY2QyxWP0NYn0Iimr6s4PJNrJOGuMAEf5SGmquh55XqJXi6zFoHPMEVYgsePIYvEF4kdAZyv5LwCU3qnQoLL8eIKtlJlcBUu3H6g1LeacOaBZoX@1AyGeo5IuJ9d5UG2Rpg8)**

Comment: Any reason for the **(pre-release)** notice? Python 3.8 was released Oct. 14, 2019.

Comment: @Noodle9 It's because the name on TIO has not been updated, if Py 3.8 is out I guess that should be updated :)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/75f00c4c7c578c8d452b27c54a2a63c42c0d8d1b/usr/share/tio.run/languages.json#L11519) is the name definition, but I'm unsure what else should be updated.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 74 bytes

```
func[a][forall a[a/1:(sign? a/1)* do reverse to""absolute a/1]max a/1 a/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvBCgIhGITv@xQ/e6pgt37Fgr30Dl3Fg@VvLJiGutHbm3aI6jDM8M1MJFNOZKTq7FTs4i9SK2lD1M6BlnqL0yrNV3@EGtcbMAEiPSgmghz6Xp9TcEum1qqbfjavYqrc4@wzWJDIBTDcqe5DhoaGX4Z8FPC3QmT8zQeObBT7A34fGEKVKi8)

Takes the input as a list of two numbers.

The 5th test case (0.0000001 0) doesn't work in TIO, but works fine in the Red console:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>(R=([h,...t])=>h?h+1<0?h+R(t):R(t)+h:t)(a)>+R(b)?R(a):R(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BboMwDL3nK3wjUYkVB7FJdKGn/QDXrlIpDYOJAYJsmjTt21nC4DZL9rP9/Gy/lZ/lXE3t6GQ/3O1Sm6U0@c3kvDD83MSI6C7C5M2pOdCT8rHgTmQhHJrMCV6K3Ldu4lT4NAvZ4uzsqnK2YODKKElBk4I0ISZDIUMlFWlPYQqBwpUj0snakglpTB8eCWSgEu0pplCtRqC8ZjVUjDTB5uzK9sPopvadC5zHrnU8eukjgfUwPZdVw7u294/l8M0AqqGfHZzbfvxwFMOKOgb7NdrKXfz7YXjfApE4bpqhs9gNr/x/4Y5gjIF6GxJ/qIVf8iOOyy8)

Input / output as strings.

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-hd` <s>53</s> <s>41</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> <s>27</s> 11 bytes (SBCS)

```
(2|¿⑶&)@MMƒ
```

*-16 bytes with new reverse t.o.s function*

### Answer History

#### 27 bytes

```
(2|᠀÷^:\-=[_^\-^]⅀&)ℝ$ℝ@MMƒ
```

-7 bytes due to using the new built-in function library which will be soon populated with helpful functions.

`MM` is the maximum function, and returns the maximum of the two items passed to it.

### 34 bytes

```
(2|᠀÷^:\-=[_^\-^]⅍⅀&)ℝ$ℝ:&^:^<[&|^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fw6jm4YKGw9vjrGJ0baPj42J042IftfY@am1Q03zUMlcFiK3U4qzibKLVauL@/7ew5DIy@a@bkQIA)

-1 byte due to using `⅍`

### 35 bytes

```
(2|᠀÷^:\-=[_^\-]^``⅀&)ℝ$ℝ:&^:^<[&|^
```

Hey, so, uh, Keg has flags now. `-hd` prints only the top item if nothing has been printed. Also, summate command works as expected now. The github interpreter works, but not TIO yet.

### 41 bytes

```
(2|᠀÷^:`-`=[_^`-`^]``∑+)&)ℝ$ℝ:&^:^<[&|^].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fw6jm4YKGw9vjrBJ0E2yj4@OAVFysQkLCo46J2ppqmo9a5qoAsZVanFWcTbRaTVys3v//hkaGXEAMAA)

-12 bytes due to not using functions

### 53 bytes

```
@m2|:&^:^<[&|^]ƒ(2|᠀÷^:`-`=[_^`-`^] ``(!;|+)&)ℝ$ℝ@mƒ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fIdeoxkotzirOJlqtJi722CQNo5qHCxoOb4@zStBNsI2OjwNScbEKCQkaitY12ppqmo9a5qoAsUPusUl6//8bGhlyATEA)

I dont even know where to begin when explaining this, but it works. I know I could remove the need for a function, but I'm on my phone, so I'll do it later.

I would have used the summate command, but there's a bug with it.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
fn($a)=>max(array_map(fn($n)=>strrev($n)*($n>0?:-1),$a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBasMwDIbveQoRArFHYqyEdtAu7TvsmoUiGptcmhg7lI2SZ89sk7JVB1v69P9CthnM@nE2g0mSTDerHllGvDnd6JuRtfRzuZFhgY6eutladQ/5mz9O8nwokRfewNej98/KzQ4aaBPw0eZY7/IC8gpl3hUbKzdYvlCsRaSvSsSqfnbKGiux27/jn0AKGQND//@wKpJwedb5zfRkFV0HYNuK5CBmHB7Ro67DBP5xF0M9Sz/VXVmnevCfAJOG7BG0rewWoLF/ltgth7SAveQgINNsGygg/RrTY7Ksvw)

Input is an array of two string numbers, example: `['123', '25.5']`.

Simply reverses both numbers as strings, then returns the max of them as numbers. To handle reversed negative numbers, the `*($n>0?:-1)` part is used which multiplies the reversed number by `1` if the original number was more than zero, else multiplies it by `-1`.

In PHP if you try to convert a string which starts with numeric values to a number, it will take the numeric part and ignore the rest. For example `'321-'` converted to a number will be `321` and the multiply operation automatically forces this numeric conversion.

Comment: Example 5 (the first of them) says output should be `1000000.0` not `1000000` as in your tests.

Comment: @KjetilS. `1000000.0` is equal to `1000000 `. I don't see a problem here, unless OP explicitly asks for reversed string outputs.

Comment: see your point (I just read the examples)

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 32 bytes

Prompts for a nested string of the two numbers.

```
⌈/⍎¨(n↑¨'¯'),¨⌽¨(n←'¯'=↑¨m)↓¨m←⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6unQf9Tbd2iFRt6jtomHVqgfWq@uqXNoxaOevRCxCSARW7BcruajtslACigINOU/UP//NC51Q2NTdQV1I0MDdS4g79B6CP/QepiIobEeSAAhb2hoZAwVPLTe2NBIz9TM3BAsaaBnAAaGQCmoZiMQG0RyAQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-g -N`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
®®w}'-Ãn@Y-X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWcgLU4&code=rq53fSctw25AWS1Y&input=WyIwIiwiMC4wMDAwMDAwMSJd)

Thanks to @Arnauld for spotting an error

```
Takes input as array of strings
U.m // for each element
(function(Z) { return Z.m // split on '-'
(function(Z) { return Z.w() // reverse and convert to number
 }, "-") }) // rejoins
.n(function(X, Y, Z) { return Y - X }) // sort in descending order

Flag -gn to output first element obtained
Flag -N to output it as a number (remove leading 0s)
```

Comment: 7 bytes: https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=rm13Jy3Dbg&input=WyIwIiwiMC4wMDAwMDAwMSJd

Comment: Also, you can't combine flags like that, and `-gn` is not a real flag. Either choose `-g1` or `-h`

Comment: @Embodiment of Ignorance the -N flag is not really necessary as leading 0 are acceptable, I'll update just use -g and -N for nice output purpose. About your improvement.. It seems not to satisfy the specifics

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, that won't work, it needs to be [8 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWhO&code=rq53fSctw24&input=WyIwIiwiMC4wMDAwMDAwMSJd). Note also that you *can* use `-gN` as a flag and that, although unusual, multiple flags can be used in some cases, particularly if one is lowercase and one is uppercase - e.g., `-g -N`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Jo King*

```perl6
&max o**.&{.abs.flip*.sign}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLTexQiFfS0tPrVovMalYLy0ns0BLrzgzPa/2vzVXcWKlQpqGSrymQlp@EZeNobGpgpGhgZ0Ol40uiK0L5Rga65kqwMQNDY2MwQK6xoZGeqZm5oYgcQM9AzAwVDCw@w8A)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfLTexQiFfS0tPrVovMalYLy0ns0BLrzgzPa/2vzVXcWKlQpqGSrymQlp@EZeNobGpgpGhgZ0Ol40uiK0L5Rga65kqwMQNDY2MwQK6xoZGeqZm5oYgcQM9AzAwVDCw@w8A) using a HyperWhatever. In an optimal world it would just be [25](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfS0tPrVovMalYLy0ns0BLrzgzPa9WLzex4r81V3FipUKahkq8pkJafhGXjaGxqYKRoYGdDpeNLoitC@UYGuuZKsDEDQ2NjMECusaGRnqmZuaGIHEDPQMwMFQwsPsPAA), but HyperWhatevers are rather disappointing

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 82 bytes

```r
options(scipen=99);b=sign(a<-scan());max(b*as.numeric(stringi::stri_reverse(b*a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxCoAwDEDRqzgmglLHqj2L1BJKhkZJVLx9pf7pDV9rPc6LDzGwxCdJ8B6XPRhngbgOlqIA4lLiC3sfbZS7kHICu5Ql8zw3bEoPqVFbELG60f1Nnasf)

Input is taken as two numbers.

Setting scipen=99 is needed to deal with more than a few decimals.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 51 bytes

```ruby
->*a{a.map{|w|(w<=>0)*"#{w.abs}".reverse.to_f}.max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsIwEAXQvacodaPFDP0Tqhvbi0iRFJKdWJLWKGnOHoMK6vbx7Dw8kmmT6CoVFF3UGBa/bPyx7eptVa6DJzW4WJLVN22dpul6NjG/e0zjPLnCnCCbXcGo@9UHxEvEL0FSpr8DsHyzkGBq9gd8OyNvRp@e)

Answer (score 2):

## [**Haskell**](https://www.haskell.org/), 70 bytes

```
f a b=max(g a)(g b)
g('-':x)=(0-).h$x
g xs=h xs
h=read @Float .reverse
```

[Try it here](https://repl.it/@tyler1/DistinctStableLaboratory)

or if Haskell language pragma aren't allowed (like TypeApplications)

## **77 bytes**

```
f a b=max(g a)(g b)
g('-':x)=(0-).h$x
g xs=h xs
h=read.reverse::String->Float
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 17 chars, 34 bytes

```
{⌈/(⍎¨⌽¨⍕¨∣⍵)××⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⌈/(⍎¨⌽¨⍕¨∣⍵)××⍵}
  f 135 210
531
  f ¯135 ¯210
¯12
  f 13.5 10
5.31
  f ¯1112313.5   ¯312.5671
¯5.3132111
  f 0.0000001 0
SYNTAX ERROR
  f 0.000001 0
100000
  f 121 121
121
  f 121 ¯3 6 0.0001 9
1000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈Ｅ²Ｉ⪫Ｅ⪪Ｓ-⮌λ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexIjO3NBdIF2gY6SiAxbzyM/PAAsEFOZklGp55BaUlwSVAPekamjoKSrpKQDIotSy1qDhVI0cTKgQG1v//6xoaGhoZGxrrmXLpGhsa6ZmamRv@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   ²            Literal `2`
  Ｅ             Map over implicit range
        Ｓ       Input string
       ⪪ -      Split on `-`s
      Ｅ         Map over substrings
           λ    Current substring
          ⮌     Reversed
     ⪫      -   Join with `-`s
    Ｉ           Cast to number
 ⌈              Maximum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Comment: ... why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ḟ€”-UV×VṠ$Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmPmtY8apirGxp2eHrYw50LVB7ubPifBRTRsX7UMEdB104ByLY@3M71cPeWYqPD7UDlkf//KykpGRqbchkZGnDpghi6IJahsZ4pF1jE0NDIGMzTNTY00jM1MzfkMtAzAAMgi8vQyBCEgYYAAA)

A monadic link taking a list of two strings and returning the maximum reversed number as a float or integer depending on the input.

### Explanation

```
ḟ€”-        | Filter out “-“ from each
    U       | Reverse each
     V      | Evaluate as Jelly code
      ×  $  | Multiply by following as a monad:
       V    | - Evaluate as Jelly code
        Ṡ   | - Sign
          Ṁ | Max
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 40 bytes

```bash
rev|sed 's/\(.*\)-/-\1/'|sort -n|tail -1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyi1rKY4NUVBvVg/RkNPK0ZTV183xlBfvaY4v6hEQTevpiQxM0dB1/D/f11DY1MuXSNDAy4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 104 bytes

```hs
r n=read((\s->if head s=='-'then"-"++reverse(drop 1 s)else reverse s)$show n)::Float
f a b=max(r a)(r b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrRCoIwFIbve4ofEdzQiUexQFiXvUR1MWmiNKdsUr29zYoOnPPzfefvlb9rY9bVwUqn1Y2xixfHoUMfAF7KRCRLr20kojR1@qGd1@zmphkEz7XxGj8bMPb99ITlTXMyk1p2HRRaOaoXc1A8nJavoxosJGY32AUxzh2oqlFSkaEDEwF4iMB8E1TlNf4/orLazNaoqMzr/YG@tZK2vUKIQEVefIZQZOsb)

The `0.0000001 0` test case doesn't work though, I think there's an error on `read`.

Typing could also be improved when the input is type `Int` for example

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 11 bytes

```
⟨v'-%v$⟩¦d⌠
```

This is a function which accepts a list of two numbers as strings and leaves the result on the stack. OP wasn't clear about whether leading 0's or 0 decimals need to be included, but the program should be equally long either way. This function does not include these 0's:

```
⟨v'-%v$d⟩¦⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//9H8FWXquqplKo/mrzy0LOVRz4L/qY/aJv6PftQwR9fQ2PRRw1wFENPI0ADIjAUA)

```
⟨       ⟩¦    Map this block over the list:
 v            Reverse the string
  '-%         Split it around -'s, leaving the separators in the result
     v        Reverse the splitting
      $       Rejoin it
         d⌠  Return the element of the list which gives the highest value when parsed as a number
```